# Getting None in variable from javascript in python

Tags: javascript, python

I am getting `None` when executing javascript and trying to get Html from iframe and store in a variable.

**Code:**

```
 html_of_iframe = self.driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.gjs-frame');")
 print(html_of_iframe)
```

Note: The same javascript returns full Html from iframe when I use it in the chrome browser console, so javascript looks fine.

**Update: Getting iframe Html in browser console like below:**

[image]

It looks like variable `html_of_iframe` is not getting the same string like browser console.

Comment: I see no return in your script.

Comment: What exactly is `None` after you execute the code? Is it a third-party page in the iframe?

Comment: None I am getting in var variable.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - Yes you are right I tried return but here I have 2 javascript statements so don't know how to use return with 2 statements.

Comment: @HelpingHands, you need to return only `iframeDocument`, so usage is pretty obvious: `return iframeDocument`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - I followed you and now it don't have any error but it also does not print html from code. same code print html of iframe in browser console. I updated screenshot in Question.

Comment: @Teemu - It is not third party page. it is iframe within web page.  You can check web page here , open it and click on preview eye and then if you inspect, you will notice everything is in iframe : https://grapesjs.com/demo.html

Comment: @HelpingHands, it should return you element. To get element html, you should use `innerHTML`

Comment: @OlvinRoght - Can you please given example based on my code?

Comment: @HelpingHands, no, I can't give you an example, cause you said that returned value is `None`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - I get none when I execute from python code. it works fine in browser console.

Comment: @HelpingHands, you're trying to execute js script just to find element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207414/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-olvin-roght).

Comment: @OlvinRoght - I am using JS to get html source from Iframe actually.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - Here is website where everything is within iframe and I am trying to get html from that iframe. : https://grapesjs.com/demo.html